# Are there any 'anti-fly' masks on the market?

Tags: clothes

I keep swallowing flies, because I'm mostly cycling along a canal.  I'm cycling quite hard, and mild hayfever means that I can't just breathe in through my nose.

I've bought a 'buff', but I'm getting too hot in that, and I'm not worried about pollution (small particles), so I'm after a lightweight mask that I can breathe through easily.  Are there any masks on the market suitable for this?

Comment: Did you check drugstores for medical masks?  (Not sure what you mean by a "buff".)

Comment: (Actually, something like a fencing mask might work, only you'd prefer something that only covers the lower face.)

Comment: (And I've seen people cycling with mosquito-netting head covers.)

Comment: Flies are primarily protein. Skip the mask and enjoy. Note that if you are an endurance athlete, you will want to mix in carbs to go with the protein at about a 4:1 ratio. Figure one PowerBar gel blast or Gu Chomp for every 5-6 flies.

Comment: @KenHiatt You should make that an answer :-) Although, I work next to a dietitian and she says flies have almost no body mass and you're going to pass them out pretty quick and so you won't be getting much protein from them. Might have to up the estimate on the number of flies per energy bar.

Comment: go cowboy style with a bandanna. seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffs are useful for a time, but I understand that they can get uncomfortable after a few kilometres. Try something like [this mask](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=8651) from Respro - you can buy replaceable filters and I think they look kind of cool too; you can even shove them in the washer after a particularly muddy or sweaty ride.

Comment: I'll give that the points!  Looks way better than anything else I've seen.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I have this mask and it is **hard** to breathe through. I use it during winter to keep my breath warm.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve heard pantyhose suggested for this purpose, though you risk looking like a bank robber and/or a lunatic.

You could also experiment with a bandana, Wild West gunslinger style.

Comment: Bandanna is good, motorcycle shops have the cool jaw bone ones.  Bonus points if you find the Darth Vader look.